# No executables found matching command 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

When trying to add a Controller in an ASP.NET Core project using Visual Studio 15 Enterprise with Update 3, I get the error below:

`"The was an error running the selected code generator: No executables found matching command 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator'"`

Answer (score 149):

If you're using csproj (Visual Studio 2017) instead of project.json, then you need to add the following to your csproj file:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Currently - Version="1.0.0"

Comment: @CountZero , I have ` Version="1.0.1"` how best to check the latest version number? And can I install this Reference using dotnet cli itself? When I tried `dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools` it created an `<PackageReference>`, but I needed a `<DotNetCliToolReference>` as johnnycardy answered here... One advantage of `dotnet add package` is that (it seems?) it will find and add an element with the latest version attribute, so I just manually converted from `<PackageReference>` -> `<DotNetCliToolReference>`

Comment: Looks like 1.0.1 is the latest unless you're using a preview. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools/

Comment: What if this line is already there in the csproj file and we are still getting the same error? I am facing this error in VS 2017 (release and latest update installed as of date)

Comment: @SteveJohnson Rebuild the solution and it should work. If not, close and reopen the solution.

Comment: is it visual studio's bug?

Comment: @SteveJohnson Did you ever get it to work? If so, what did you do. The line is already in csproj, and dotnet restore appears to work but when I open manage nuget packages, the CodeGeneration.Tools is still not installed.

Comment: @user5389726598465 Yes I did. It was because of a dependency in the project file which was not compatible with the "then version" of the .NET CORE I was using. I removed that dependency and chose the correct the preview release and it worked. Now I am on .NET CORE 2.0 and upgraded all my dependencies to .NET CORE 2.0 So i dont have the problem anymore. I am sorry I donot recall that specific incompatible dependency.

Comment: @user5389726598465
My current depencies look like these:

Comment: @SteveJohnson Thank you. Lol I figured out that that was the problem (everything is now 2.0.0), and  solved the codegenerator still not being found by using the dos cmd prompt for the cmd. Details here for future readers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765196/why-cant-i-install-microsoft-visualstudio-web-codegeneration-tools-2-0-1-via-nu

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Mac (OS X) or any supported distribution of Linux, you have to run:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 2.2.3
```

Additionally, on Mac I added to my `.zshrc` (or bash equivalent)

```
export PATH=$HOME/.dotnet/tools:$PATH
```

And I had to make sure to restart Terminal.

Comment: Adding .dotnet/tools to my PATH in Mint 19 solved my problem.

Answer (score 7):

For the latest version, in project.json add the following under dependencies:

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
  "type": "build",
  "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
}
```

and the following under tools:

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is no "project.json" file for the newest asp.net core version.

Answer (score 7):

A more robust answer than copying version numbers into your configuration file is to use NuGet to ensure that the packages are added to your project.

Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution.

First, get everything up to date. Choose the Updates tab. Check the box for Update All and run this a few times. Don't be surprised if some stuff downgrades the first couple of times you run the upgrade. Some dependencies seem to have to be handled sequentially. It took me about 5 upgrades to get everything up to date.

Then, in the browse tab, search for `CodeGeneration.Tools`. Install it. Do the same for `CodeGenerators.Mvc`. As you find additional error messages, you should be able to find any missing packages in NuGet.

Comment: This is what I see when I try to install `CodeGeneration.Tools` to my project: `Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.0.1' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project`

Answer (score 4):

In dotnet core 2.1.1 you'd expect that the situation has changed and you may not need to add much. I'm sorry to annoy you but the situation is same and all you need to do now is update your version of the tool or package you wish to use.

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This worked for me. I hope it works for eveyone else that gets stuck here. Note that the key reference is `DotNetCliToolReference` not `PackageReference`

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your project.json:

Under dependencies:

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "type": "build"
}
```

Under tools:

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
}
```

- Version number may change depending on which version of .NET Core you're using in your project
- You may get another error about Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions missing, in which case you'll need to get from NuGet
- Make sure "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" version in dependencies matches "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" version in tools

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution and specifically describing variation of version # for different users etc. It saved me tons of hours.

Answer (score 2):

1. I had to add the following to my CSProj file:

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
</ItemGroup>
```

2. After adding that I installed CodeGenerators.Mvc with nuget package manager.
3. I was still getting an error saying it can't find some file in the MCD folder so I had to copy and paste the entire bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1 folder into bin\MCD\Debug\netcoreapp1.1

I ran the scaffolding and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue in Visual Studio Mac Community Edition 2017. Prior to running the `scaffold` command from the project directory, make sure the directory has the `Program.cs`, `Startup.cs` and `.csproj` files. if not, then run the command `ls-al` and then `cd` into the project directory which would be inside your current project directory and then execute the `scaffold` command. An obvious mistake many overlook.

Comment: This was the solution for me (and you're right very obvious! LOL). I was using JetBrains Rider (which has a solution and separate sub folder for project) and following instructions for vscode which doesn't. Once I jumped into the project folder not the solution it worked. Rider defaults it's Terminal to the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add tag 'DotNetCliToolReference ' and package code design on .csproj and **execute code-generate command on root solution**. Thats worked to me.

**.csproj**
 `<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>`

`<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>`

**Command**
 `PS C:\Users\miche\projetos\asp_net_core\crud> dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name ProdutosController -m Produto -dc AppDataContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries`

Don't forget to build and restore solution after add package ;)

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2015, in project.json file -

under dependencies add -

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

then under tools add-

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code change your yourproject.csproj

```
<pre>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.6" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" version= "2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" version= "2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
  </ItemGroup>`enter code here`
</pre>
```

Comment: pre tag is not there

Answer (score 0):

I just typed in Linux:

```sh
~/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -m Movie -dc RazorPagesMovieContext -udl -outDir Pages/Movies --referenceScriptLibraries
```

So, I did not start with 'dotnet' (my current version: 2.2.300)

I do not like this solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

## On Windows 10

In my case the installer added the wrong path to the `Path` environment variable.
The path added was pointing to a non existing folder under Programs. It needs to point to `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator.exe`.
For me the correct path was in my user folder: `~\.dotnet\tools`

You can check if the correct path was added by running: `echo $env:Path`
If the path is missing or incorrect you just need to add the correct path to the `Path` system environment variable.

You might be able to test this by using PowerShell to set your local variable: `$env:Path += ";C:\Users\<YOUR_NAME_HERE>\.dotnet\tools"`
*But I haven't tried this.*

---

### To fix it globally

1. Start typing `Environment` in the windows search and you should see the `Control panel` option to `Edit system environment variables`.
2. Click the `Environment Variables...` button in the lower right corner.
3. Under `System variables` find and select the `Path` variable, then click `Edit`.
4. Check if the path to `dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator.exe` is there and if not click `New` and add it.
5. Restart your computer.