# dotnet core PackageReference vs DotNetCliToolReference

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to run `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator` from my comand line. The first time I tried, I got the error `No executable found matching command "dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator"`

I realized I needed to install the `aspnet-codegenerator` as "dotnet CLI tool" (part of their [extensibility model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/extensibility) allows adding CLI commands  if I include the correct `<DotNetCliToolReference>` element to the csproj file.)<sup>1</sup>

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42482751/1175496) tells me which `<DotNetCliToolReference>` I need, i.e. `<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />` but it leaves me with a few questions:

1. Can I install that using the command line rather than hand-editing
   the csproj?

   - I notice I can install packages using the command `dotnet add
     package`, but that adds the element `<PackageReference>` and I need `<DotNetCliToolReference>` ;
   - i.e. running the command would produce this (wrong) element: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />`
2. What's the difference between those two elements?

   - Can I add them to the same `<ItemGroup>`?
   - When I have a `csproj` whose first and only `<ItemGroup>` contains a `<DotNetCliToolReference>`, then any subsequent `dotnet add package` commands fail:  `error: Invalid restore input. Invalid restore input. DotnetCliToolReference-BundlerMinifier.Core Input files:`.
   - My workaround is to:

     1. remove any existing `DotNetCliToolReference`  elements
     2. run `dotnet add package`
     3. After finished, add back what I removed.

<sup>1</sup>  (I'm in Visual Studio Code and using the latest; so we're using csproj, not project.json)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. At the moment adding `DotNetCliToolReference` items is only possibly by hand-editing the csproj file.  The feature was deprecated in .NET Core 3.0, because it caused strange incompatibilities that were difficult to debug.  See: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3115
2. The logical difference is that `PackageReference`s will become part of your application - you can use the dlls shipped with the package from your code and it will be deployed with your app. `DotNetCliToolReference` packages will be restored from feeds but not added to your app's "dependency graph". When the CLI runs commands it looks at the csproj file as well to resolve command names to the corresponding dll files through `DotNetCliToolReference` items.
3. It does not matter in which item groups those two item types are. MSBuild is very dynamic and you can re-arrange the file as you like. Both the CLI and NuGet use MSBuild API to evaluate the file and query the project's items.
4. The error you are seeing that `dotnet add package` fails when a `DotNetCliToolReference` is already present is a bug that has been fixed for the upcoming 2.0 release: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4771

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Only other question, any trick to find the latest Version attribute? When I use `dotnet add package` and omit version argument, the resulting element, will its version attribute value represent the latest? Any other trick to get the latest version? Maybe a version pattern could work?

Comment: `dotnet add package` will choose that latest version, but you can also pass wildcards like `9.*` and it will write these to the project file. However, this is a bit dangerous in practice since you might get different results when packages are updated and your build is not "reproducible". But it's useful for pre-release versions (e.g. `1.2.3-preview1-*`).

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on 2. ? What do you mean "restored from feeds" ?

Comment: @DavidRefaeli it means "downloaded or copied from configured feeds" (depending on what is in nuget.config)

Comment: If you stumble upon this answer searching for how to add "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet". It is no longer needed to add it to `<DotNetCliToolReference>` since after Core 2.1 it is now part of the SDK. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/dotnet/core/migration/20-21)

Comment: Also `DotNetCliToolReference` is kind of soft-deprecated now that there are both global and local tools with .NET Core 3.0

Comment: as Martin note, `DotNetCliToolReference` limit to .NET Core 2.2 and below. We need move to .Net Core Local tools instead. https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3115