# asp.net core 2.0 has Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration files in output folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I've created a new asp.net core 2.0 mvc web app using Visual Studio 2017.

It has a reference to NuGet package "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" (2.0.0) which, it appears is required if I want to be able to scaffold views/controllers. (A feature which I require)

When I publish my web app, I wouldn't expect to see what (appears to be) a development dependency being published to my output folder... and yet, I have a bunch of assemblies such as

**`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.dll, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating.dll, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils.dll`**

etc.

Am I doing something wrong? : How can I reduce all these extra dlls?  There's one (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll) which is ~2Mb!

Answer (score 5):

Try editing the csproj file to replace the PackageReference elements for those packages with DotNetCliToolReference elements, e.g.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

becomes

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
```

With this change, those packages should still be available as tools but will not be included with the packaged website.

See [dotnet core PackageReference vs DotNetCliToolReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169037/dotnet-core-packagereference-vs-dotnetclitoolreference)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the PrivateAssets to all in the csproj file, this worked for me. There is a really good [thread](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4125) describing this issue.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Comment: I have the following, but I still get the extra DLLs in my published site:     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" PrivateAssets="All" />

Comment: Try copying the code in the answer and replace the Version with 2.0.3. The code you provided is adding the PrivateAssets as an attribute but that is not what the answer is doing.

Comment: That didn't help. What did help... changing it from a PackageReference to a DotNetCliToolReference. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169037/dotnet-core-packagereference-vs-dotnetclitoolreference

Comment: Just wondering, what does it say on package source in your visual studio? On mine says it's using the Microsoft Visual studio offline packages

Answer (score 0):

I'm referencing the package only in Debug builds:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"  />
```

That way, it won't appear in a release build. The same goes for the Razor runtime compilation package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`.