# How can I automatically run a dotnet tool during compilation

Tags: msbuild, nuget, dotnet-tool

I want to write a NuGet package that automatically executes a [dotnet tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools#install-a-local-tool) prior to compilation. The dotnet tool will process a file, and generate (non-code) output.

This is easily done by adding a `.targets` file to my NuGet package:

```
\build
  \My.Package.targets
```

where we `Exec` the tool:

```xml
<!-- My.Package.targets -->
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FilesToProcess Include="**/*.my_extension" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Run Tool" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">      
    <Exec Command="dotnet my-tool -input %(FilesToProcess.Identity)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

However, this still requires the user to create a tool manifest, and install the tool before building the project.

```
dotnet new tool-manifest
dotnet tool install My.Tool
```

I want to make this automatic - the process for the developer should be as simple as "install a NuGet package, which will install/reference the tool automatically".

I've considered:

- Using `DotNetCliToolReference` to reference the tool, but that hasn't been supported since .NET Core 2.2.
- Using Source Generators, but they have 2 key limitations: they can only generate code files, not any other kind of file; and they don't permit IO.
- Adding instructions to the Readme about how to install the tool, e.g.

  > Please remember to run `dotnet new tool-manifest` and `dotnet tool install My.Tool` before building this project

  but I'm a strong believer in reducing friction when starting on a new project. I try and automate anything past "clone the repository, and open the solution in your editor of choice".
- Rewriting the tool as an MSBuild task, but I don't own the tool - it's a 3rd party tool.

Related questions:

- [dotnet core PackageReference vs DotNetCliToolReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169037/dotnet-core-packagereference-vs-dotnetclitoolreference)
- [Using PackageDownload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77838917/how-can-i-automatically-run-a-dotnet-tool-during-compilation). This works, but is a little hacky.

Comment: In your package's .targets file, add a set of targets. Add a target that checks if `dotnet-tools.json` exists and if it doesn't uses the `Exec` task to run `dotnet new tool-manifest`. Add a target that depends on the 'create tool manifest file' target that checks if `my-tool` is in the manifest and if it isn't uses the `Exec` task to run `dotnet tool install my-tool`. Add a target that depends on the install target that exec's `dotnet tool restore`. Modify the `RunTool` target to depend on the target that restores the tool.